# Destroy Javascript Datepicker Onblur

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a javascript datepicker which works perfectly, with one exception.  If the user tabs out of the form field without selecting a date, the datepicker remains on the screen.  I need to destroy onBlur but not sure where.

The function calling the date picker in the body is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Datepicker/datepickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new datepickr('effectiveDate', {
            'dateFormat': 'n/j/Y'
        });
    </script>
```

The content of the js file is:

```
var datepickr = (function() {
var datepickrs = [],
currentDate = new Date(setAllDates(3)),
date = {
    current: {
        year: function() {
            return currentDate.getFullYear();
        },
        month: {
            integer: function() {
                return currentDate.getMonth();
            },
            string: function(full) {
                var date = currentDate.getMonth();
                return monthToStr(date, full);
            }
        },
        day: function() {
            return currentDate.getDate();           
        }
    },
    month: {
        string: function(full, currentMonthView) {
            var date = currentMonthView;
            return monthToStr(date, full);
        },
        numDays: function(currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
            // checks to see if february is a leap year otherwise     return the respective # of days
            return (currentMonthView == 1 && !(currentYearView & 3) &&     (currentYearView % 1e2 || !(currentYearView % 4e2))) ? 29 : daysInMonth[currentMonthView];
        }
    }
},
weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wednes', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Satur'],
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],
suffix = { 1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 21: 'st', 22: 'nd', 23: 'rd', 31: 'st' },
buildCache = [],
handlers = {
    calendarClick: function(e) {
        if(e.target.className) {
            switch(e.target.className) {
                case 'prev-month':
                case 'prevMonth':
                    this.currentMonthView--;
                    if(this.currentMonthView < 0) {
                        this.currentYearView--;
                        this.currentMonthView = 11;
                    }
                    rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                break;
                case 'next-month':
                case 'nextMonth':
                    this.currentMonthView++;
                    if(this.currentMonthView > 11) {
                        this.currentYearView++;
                        this.currentMonthView = 0;
                    }
                    rebuildCalendar.call(this);
                break;
                case 'day':
                    this.element.value = formatDate(new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, e.target.innerHTML).getTime(), this.config.dateFormat);
                    this.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    documentClick: function(e) {
        if(e.target != this.element && e.target != this.calendar) {
            var parentNode = e.target.parentNode;
            if(parentNode != this.calender) {
                while(parentNode != this.calendar) {
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                    if(parentNode == null) {
                        this.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function formatDate(milliseconds, dateFormat) {
    var formattedDate = '',
    dateObj = new Date(milliseconds),
    format = {
        d: function() {
            var day = format.j();
            return (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
        },
        D: function() {
            return weekdays[format.w()].substring(0, 3);
        },
        j: function() {
            return dateObj.getDate();
        },
        l: function() {
            return weekdays[format.w()] + 'day';
        },
        S: function() {
            return suffix[format.j()] || 'th';
        },
        w: function() {
            return dateObj.getDay();
        },
        F: function() {
            return monthToStr(format.n(), true);
        },
        m: function() {
            var month = format.n() + 1;
            return (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
        },
        M: function() {
            return monthToStr(format.n(), false);
        },
        n: function() {
            return dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
        },
        Y: function() {
            return dateObj.getFullYear();
        },
        y: function() {
            return format.Y().toString().substring(2, 4);
        }
    },
    formatPieces = dateFormat.split('');

    foreach(formatPieces, function(formatPiece) {
        formattedDate += format[formatPiece] ? format[formatPiece]() : formatPiece;
    });

    return formattedDate;
}

function foreach(items, callback) {
    var i = 0, x = items.length;
    for(i; i < x; i++) {
        if(callback(items[i], i) === false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function addEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.attachEvent) {
        var fixedCallback = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault = (function(e) {
                return function() { e.returnValue = false; }
            })(e);
            e.stopPropagation = (function(e) {
                return function() { e.cancelBubble = true; }
            })(e);
            e.target = e.srcElement;
            callback.call(element, e);
        };
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, fixedCallback);
    }
}

function removeEvent(element, eventType, callback) {
    if(element.removeEventListener) {
        element.removeEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else if(element.detachEvent) {
        element.detachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
    }
}

function buildNode(nodeName, attributes, content) {
    var element;

    if(!(nodeName in buildCache)) {
        buildCache[nodeName] = document.createElement(nodeName);
    }

    element = buildCache[nodeName].cloneNode(false);

    if(attributes != null) {
        for(var attribute in attributes) {
            element[attribute] = attributes[attribute];
        }
    }

    if(content != null) {
        if(typeof(content) == 'object') {
            element.appendChild(content);
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = content;
        }
    }

    return element;
}

function monthToStr(date, full) {
    return ((full == true) ? months[date] : ((months[date].length > 3) ? months[date].substring(0, 3) : months[date]));
}

function isToday(day, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    return day == date.current.day() && currentMonthView == date.current.month.integer() && currentYearView == date.current.year();
}

function buildWeekdays() {
    var weekdayHtml = document.createDocumentFragment();
    foreach(weekdays, function(weekday) {
        weekdayHtml.appendChild(buildNode('th', {}, weekday.substring(0, 2)));
    });
    return weekdayHtml;
}

function rebuildCalendar() {
    while(this.calendarBody.hasChildNodes()){
        this.calendarBody.removeChild(this.calendarBody.lastChild);
    }

    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView, 1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView);

    this.currentMonth.innerHTML = date.month.string(this.config.fullCurrentMonth, this.currentMonthView) + ' ' + this.currentYearView;
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
}

function buildCurrentMonth(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    return buildNode('span', { className: 'current-month' }, date.month.string(config.fullCurrentMonth, currentMonthView) + ' ' + currentYearView);
}

function buildMonths(config, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var months = buildNode('div', { className: 'months' }),
    prevMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'prev-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'prevMonth' }, '&lt;')),
    nextMonth = buildNode('span', { className: 'next-month' }, buildNode('span', { className: 'nextMonth' }, '&gt;'));

    months.appendChild(prevMonth);
    months.appendChild(nextMonth);

    return months;
}

function buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays, currentMonthView, currentYearView) {
    var calendarBody = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    row = buildNode('tr'),
    dayCount = 0, i;

    // print out previous month's "days"
    for(i = 1; i <= firstOfMonth; i++) {
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
        dayCount++;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
        // if we have reached the end of a week, wrap to the next line
        if(dayCount == 7) {
            calendarBody.appendChild(row);
            row = buildNode('tr');
            dayCount = 0;
        }

        var todayClassName = isToday(i, currentMonthView, currentYearView) ? { className: 'today' } : null;
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', todayClassName, buildNode('span', { className: 'day' }, i)));

        dayCount++;
    }

    // if we haven't finished at the end of the week, start writing out the "days" for the next month
    for(i = 1; i <= (7 - dayCount); i++) {
        row.appendChild(buildNode('td', null, '&nbsp;'));
    }

    calendarBody.appendChild(row);

    return calendarBody;
}

function buildCalendar() {
    var firstOfMonth = new Date(this.currentYearView, this.currentMonthView,     1).getDay(),
    numDays = date.month.numDays(this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView),
    self = this;

    var inputLeft = inputTop = 0,
    obj = this.element;

    if(obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            inputLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
            inputTop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }

    var calendarContainer = buildNode('div', { className: 'calendar' });
    calendarContainer.style.cssText = 'display: none; position: absolute; top:     ' + (inputTop + this.element.offsetHeight) + 'px; left: ' + inputLeft + 'px; z-index: 100;';

    this.currentMonth = buildCurrentMonth(this.config, this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView)
    var months = buildMonths(this.config, this.currentMonthView,     this.currentYearView);
    months.appendChild(this.currentMonth);

    var calendar = buildNode('table', null, buildNode('thead', null, buildNode    ('tr', { className: 'weekdays' }, buildWeekdays())));
    this.calendarBody = buildNode('tbody');
    this.calendarBody.appendChild(buildDays(firstOfMonth, numDays,     this.currentMonthView, this.currentYearView));
    calendar.appendChild(this.calendarBody);

    calendarContainer.appendChild(months);
    calendarContainer.appendChild(calendar);

    document.body.appendChild(calendarContainer);

    addEvent(calendarContainer, 'click', function(e) { handlers.calendarClick.call(self, e); });

    return calendarContainer;
}

return function(elementId, userConfig) {
    var self = this;

    this.element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    this.config = {
        fullCurrentMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'F jS, Y'
    };
    this.currentYearView = date.current.year();
    this.currentMonthView = date.current.month.integer();

    if(userConfig) {
        for(var key in userConfig) {
            if(this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.config[key] = userConfig[key];
            }
        }
    }

    this.documentClick = function(e) { handlers.documentClick.call(self, e); }

    this.open = function(e) {
        addEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);

        foreach(datepickrs, function(datepickr) {
            if(datepickr != self) {
                datepickr.close();
            }
        });

        self.calendar.style.display = 'block';
    }

    this.close = function() {
        removeEvent(document, 'click', self.documentClick);
        self.calendar.style.display = 'none';
    }

    this.calendar = buildCalendar.call(this);

    datepickrs.push(this);

    if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
        addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
    } else {
        addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this (look at the end of datepickr.js):

```
if(this.element.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    addEvent(this.element, 'focus', this.open);
    addEvent(this.element, 'blur', this.close); // <--- Add this line
} else {
    addEvent(this.element, 'click', this.open);
}
```

Comment: It's very bad to modify libraries directly.

Comment: It is not if you are the one who created the library :-)
If not, you can always submit bug/feature request to the author.

Comment: Well I doubt he would be asking this question if he was the creator of the library =P

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new datepickr('effectiveDate', {
    'dateFormat': 'n/j/Y'
});

document.getElementById('effectiveDate').addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
    d.close();
});
```